# Where does Adidas Micoach loads music files?

Tags: music

I have a lot of music on my android phone that I want to listen when im running and using Adidas Micoach apk to trainning that I cant listen because Micoach doesn't list the music files on his player. I take a look and didn't find any option to load music from specific path on SD on micoach. Does someone knows where Adidas Micoach loads it's list of music?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this review](http://www.androidtapp.com/adidas-micoach/), you may need to create playlists in the Android's stock Music player app, and miCoach will pull those playlists in.